# Translate PHP function to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I currently fetch a GET-param via PHP and run through at PHP function. Now I need that value for a jQuery script on the site. So how can I do the following in jQuery?

```
function trimQuery($query){

    $query = trim($query);

    $query = preg_replace("/[^a-zåäö0-9\s]/i","",$query);

    return $query;

}

$trimmedQuery = trimQuery($_GET['q']);

$arrayTrimmedQuery = explode(" ",trimmedQuery );

foreach(arrayTrimmedQuery as $value){

  echo $value;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I have kept the same code structure and variable names. This function is pure JavaScript (without any jQuery function).

```
function trimQuery($query){
    $query = $query.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");//Equivalent to jQuery.trim($query)
    $query = $query.replace(/[^a-zåäö0-9\s]/gi, "");
    return $query;
}

var q = location.search.match(/&q=([^&]+)/);
q = q ? q[1] : "";
var $trimmedQuery = trimQuery(q);

var $arrayTrimmedQuery = trimmedQuery.split(" ");

for(var i=0; i<$arrayTrimmedQuery.length; i++){
    var $value = $arrayTrimmedQuery[i];
    alert($value);
}
```

Comment: Note: If you're not sure about a function, visit Google, and use `<keyword> mdn` (mdn = Mozilla Developer Network, the #1 JavaScript documentation source). Example: `replace mdn`

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimQuery(query){

    query = $.trim(query);

    query = query.replace(/[^a-zåäö0-9\s]/i,"");

    return query;

}

trimmedQuery = trimQuery($('input').val());

arrayTrimmedQuery = trimmedQuery.split(" ");

for(var value in arrayTrimmedQuery){

  document.write(value);

}
```

Comment: How is this JavaScript? `foreach` and `$_GET` are not defined in JavaScript.

Comment: Didn't know what he wanted with $_GET